# how to increase the width of list in ionic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a list as shown in image.I am able to make a list using **ng-repeat** but my child elements not same as shown in image why ? I used nested **ng-repeat**..could you please tell me where i am doing wrong to make same list as shown in figure ?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is my code
http://play.ionic.io/app/8a3d7bbaf403

```
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item  style="background-color:grey;" ng-repeat="item in collect track by $index">
          <p style="color:white;">{{item.childName }}</p>
          <ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="i in item.grandChildren">
    {{i.grandChildName}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
        </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: @GuruprasadRao No please check image ..!! only header has grey background ..and there child have white ..

Comment: That should be some `CSS` issue right?

Comment: yes there is two issue in my code..first only header is gray background .and there child have same width as parent..please check my image

Comment: You see `style="background-color:grey;"` on `ion-item` for `header`? Same thing add it for `ion-item` `repeat`

Comment: Actually "Report to Report" , "Order To cash " only have gray background ..and there child "frame asset" have light grey background and also same width as parent

Comment: Something like **[this](http://play.ionic.io/app/d9a5ef08c9fc)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91757/discussion-between-shruti-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: No you didn't get my question...Please check my image .In list there is header and there childs .both have same width ..the difference between header is header have background color of gray and children have light grey

Comment: did you get my point ..? Actually list show the headers and its item ..header have background colour gray  and it item have light grey background color

Comment: From where you got that pic.. I mean u had any demo online..?

Comment: no i don't have i got some thing in ionic site http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-dividers..i am trying to implement this

Comment: I got it This type of list I need to implement http://play.ionic.io/app/287a40348400

Comment: could you please please add number as you did in above demo

Comment: As you added 24,11,09,08 number in list how I will add in my lsit

Comment: **[here is that drmo](http://play.ionic.io/app/d9a5ef08c9fc)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the padding from the 'child' list items and then add the same padding only around the 'child' title.

I changed your html a bit to use classes and I wrapped the title in a `div`

```
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in collect track by $index" class="child-item">
        <div class="child-title">{{item.childName }}</div>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="i in item.grandChildren">
            <span class="grandchild-name">{{i.grandChildName}}!</span>
            <span class="grandchild-count">{{i.grandChildCount}}</span>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Then in your CSS you can use these classes

```
.child-item {
   background-color: grey;
   padding: 0;
}
.child-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: -1px;
}
.grandchild-count {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Link to sample: http://play.ionic.io/app/2bb6c01bd2cb

And the output now looks like this:

[![list output][1]][1]